# It looks like some packages were installed twice

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, disk-usage

I run `dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n` and see that there are quite a few packages that look duplicated. That is, some package names appear twice and have similar size. I see this:

[image]

Does this mean that, somehow, I have a redundant copy of each of these packages on my machine, and they're taking up space unnecessarily? If not, what's happening here? If so, how can I fix this?

I'm using 18.04.1.

Comment: It could be you are using multiarch, one version for example is x86_64, the other x86 (used by Pol/Wine or other software you have loaded). You can't call a x86_64 (64bit library) from a 32bit program, the API/ABI's don't match, so x86 libs are called, thus both will be installed.

Comment: If so, is this normal and unavoidable? Or am I eating up disk space for no good reason?

Comment: The Ubuntu system I am running has no x86  (just x86_64 & noarch (which work for all).  This single-architecture would be normal on an install.  However if you add certain applications which aren't your architecture (eg. wine, pol, skype was x86 but I don't know if still is etc) then to install & use those programs your system requires it.  It's *not* unique here, I recently had to fix a windoze7 machine where 'wow' (windoze on windoze) caused duplication there so legacy apps could run on the box.  The reason is you've installed apps/programs that require it; only you can know if worth it.